# Telethon - change session file path

Tags: telegram, telethon

I want to reuse existing session file (the phonenumber.session) file,

But I want to change it default path (working directory) to another directory, like '/data/se.session'

There is any option to do that in telethon?

```
client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
```

When using [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp), the TelegramClient constructor get session file path as input..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking at telethon source code, I found [this](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/4b16183d2bbe80cbf4dabdb266a8015c5bf975cc/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py#L74),

```
    session (`str` | `telethon.sessions.abstract.Session`, `None`):
        The file name of the session file to be used if a string is
        given (it may be a full path), or the Session instance to be
        used otherwise. If it's `None`, the session will not be saved,
        and you should call :meth:`.log_out()` when you're done.
        Note that if you pass a string it will be a file in the current
        working directory, although you can also pass absolute paths.
        The session file contains enough information for you to login
        without re-sending the code, so if you have to enter the code
        more than once, maybe you're changing the working directory,
        renaming or removing the file, or using random names.
```

In general, when creating TelegramClient object - pass it the full path to session file

```
client = TelegramClient('path/to/session.session',api_id,app_hash)
```

Comment: You can mark your answer as correct if it solves your problem.

Comment: I test it working without the .session extension
e.g:
client = TelegramClient('path/to/session',api_id,app_hash)